# The event dispatched from a html page is not received by main.js in my firefox extension

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

In my firefox extension I need user input to do further computations on my extension.
I used a panel to do this. With panels I can get input form user and pass it to my content script and emit this from there using **self.port.emit** and receive it on ***main.js*** using **panel.port.on**. But my problem is panels auto hide. I want to show my panel until user closes it.

I tried getting the above scenario by opening a html page using window **window.open**. But I could not pass the user input from my html window to ***main.js***. I used the following code.

MY **SR.html** code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <script>
    var t= {
    CallExtension : function(e) {
        var text = document.getElementById("p").value;
        var element = document.createElement("MyExtDE");
        element.setAttribute("phNu", text);
        document.documentElement.appendChild(element);
        var evt = document.createEvent("Events");
        evt.initEvent("SREvent", true, false);
        element.dispatchEvent(evt);
     }
     }
</script>
    <style>
        table{ padding-top:30px;}
        h1{ color:orange; }
        td{ font-family:"Arial"; font-size:12px; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table cellspacing=5 cellpadding=5 align="center" border=0>
        <tr> 
            <td colspan=3><h1>MyRMN Start Registration</h1></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Phone Number</td><td>:</td><td><input type="text" id="p" name="pn"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
    <td><input type="button" id="btnSSubmit" value="Submit"        
             onclick="t.CallExtension(event);" /></td>
         </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

My **main.js** code

```
function SR(){
   try {
      win = window.open(data.url("SR.html"), "SR",  
      "chrome,centerscreen");
      win.document.defaultView.addEventListener("SREvent", S1Submit, false, true);
      //window.window.document.defaultView.addEventListener("SREvent", S1Submit, false, 
      true); 
    } catch(e) {
    prompts.alert(null, "main() SR", " Exception: " + e);
  }

}

function S1Submit(evt){
    var text = evt.target.getAttribute("phNu");
    prompts.alert(null, "main() S1Submit", text);
    if (text) {
      mSR(text);
    }
}
```

## UPDATE

---

I introduced page-mod in my main.js page and i could not still communicate with my main.js
from my webpage.

**main.js**

```
var data = require("sdk/self").data;
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");

function StartRegistration(){
    try {
    winSReg = window.open(null, data.url("SR.html"), "Title", 
        "chrome,centerscreen", null);
    } catch(e) {
        prompts.alert(null, "Title", "SR Exception: " + e);
    }
}

pageMod.PageMod({
    include: data.url("SR.html"),
    contentScriptFile: data.url("SR.js"),
    onAttach: function(worker) {
       worker.port.on("gotInput", function(inputValue) {
       doSomethingWith(inputValue);
    });
  }
});
```

**SR.JS**

```
function SubmitSReg(){
    try {
        var text = document.getElementById("p").value;
        alert("SR.js text:" + text);
        self.port.emit("gotInput", text); 
    } catch(e) {
        alert(e);
    }
}
```

**SR.Html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>SR</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="SR.js"></script>
    <style>
    table{ padding-top:30px;}
    h1{ color:orange; }
    td{ font-family:"Arial"; font-size:12px; }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table cellspacing=5 cellpadding=5 align="center" border=0>
            <tr> 
                <td colspan=3><h1>Title</h1></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Phone Number</td><td>:</td><td><input type="text" id="p" 
                name="pn" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
        <td><input type="button" id="btnSSubmit" value="Submit" onclick = 
                "SubmitSReg()"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any kind of help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is right but there's a missing part: in order to allow communication between the main.js and your static page you need to use a [page-mod](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod) matching your static page local url.

Add this to your main.js:

```
var data = require("sdk/self").data;
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");

pageMod.PageMod({
    include: data.url("SR.html"),
    contentScriptFile: [data.url("script.js")],
    onAttach: function(worker) {
      worker.port.on("gotInput", function(inputValue) {
        doSomethingWith(inputValue);
      });
    }
});
```

And also create a data/script.js file containing:

```
/* Here add a listener to the form's submit event and then
get the input element and its value.
Then do this with yhe input value:
*/
self.port.emit('gotInput', inputValue);
```

This way you achieve communication between your page and the addon main.js.

Comment: Hello @matagus Thanks for your help, I am still not able to get any desired outcome. Do have any thoughts on this. Please see my updated code for reference

Comment: and get the following error from my script(sr.js) "TypeError: self.port is undefined"